# Check for primality number

Tags: c++, c, primes

I had come across a code solution to check whether any number if prime or not.

```
int isPrime(int N){
    if(N<=1){
        return 0;
    }
    if(N==2 || N==3){
        return 1;
    }
    if(N%2==0 or N%3==0){
        return 0;
    }
    for(int i=5;i*i<=N;i=i+6){
        if(N%i==0 || N%(i+2) ==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Can anyone explain, why we are increasing i=i+6 and condition N%(i+2)==0??

We are checking N%i==0 then why we are checking it for i+2?

Comment: The explanation is found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Just read *Simple methods"

Comment: Pop quiz: what does the shown code determine for  `2` and `3`, are they prime or not; and what do you get when you multiply these two numbers together, and what does that mean, with respect to all the other prime numbers that could possibly exist?

Comment: For every batch of 6 numbers, you know that three of them are divisible by 2 and two of them are divisible by 3, with one divisible by both. That leaves two numbers out of every batch of six divisors to test.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik According to this code 2 and 3 are prime number and 6 is not prime number

Comment: ...so for the first batch of 6 divisors (5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10) you need test only 5 (`i`) and 7 (`i+2`), because 6, 8, 9, and 10 are all divisible by 2 or 3, and you already tested whether `N` is divisible by 2 or 3. If `N` isn't divisible by 2 or 3 then it is not divisible by multiples of 2 and 3 either.

Comment: @Gunther I got it why we are doing N%i but why we are again checking it for i+2?

Comment: Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization).

Answer (score 2):

Starting from 4 every second number is not prime. Starting from 6 every third number is not prime. Now consider what is left

```
        4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
2+x*2   x   x   x    x     x     x     x
3+y*3       x     x        x       x
others    5   7        11    13          17   19 ...
```

The pattern continues and has a length of 2*3 = 6.